# How to update Keyword in Google adwords API(Java)?

Tags: java, google-api, google-ads-api, google-ad-manager

I am new to Google AdWords API. There is no mention of Keyword in UpdateKeyword class of Google AdWords API, It is only used to update MaxCPC using criterionId. Normally Google AdWords API's are pretty simple, but I am not getting how to update keyword properties.
How do I update keyword, KeywordmMatchType, and maxCPC?

```
  public static void runExample(
      AdWordsServicesInterface adWordsServices,
      AdWordsSession session,
      Long adGroupId,
      Long keywordId)
      throws RemoteException {
    // Get the AdGroupCriterionService.
    AdGroupCriterionServiceInterface adGroupCriterionService =
        adWordsServices.get(session, AdGroupCriterionServiceInterface.class);

    // Create ad group criterion with updated bid.
    Criterion criterion = new Criterion();
    criterion.setId(keywordId);

    BiddableAdGroupCriterion biddableAdGroupCriterion = new BiddableAdGroupCriterion();
    biddableAdGroupCriterion.setAdGroupId(adGroupId);
    biddableAdGroupCriterion.setCriterion(criterion);

    // Create bids.
    BiddingStrategyConfiguration biddingStrategyConfiguration = new BiddingStrategyConfiguration();
    CpcBid bid = new CpcBid();
    bid.setBid(new Money(null, 10000000L));
    biddingStrategyConfiguration.setBids(new Bids[] {bid});
    biddableAdGroupCriterion.setBiddingStrategyConfiguration(biddingStrategyConfiguration);

    // Create operations.
    AdGroupCriterionOperation operation = new AdGroupCriterionOperation();
    operation.setOperand(biddableAdGroupCriterion);
    operation.setOperator(Operator.SET);

    AdGroupCriterionOperation[] operations = new AdGroupCriterionOperation[] {operation};

    // Update ad group criteria.
    AdGroupCriterionReturnValue result = adGroupCriterionService.mutate(operations);

    // Display ad group criteria.
    for (AdGroupCriterion adGroupCriterionResult : result.getValue()) {
      if (adGroupCriterionResult instanceof BiddableAdGroupCriterion) {
        biddableAdGroupCriterion = (BiddableAdGroupCriterion) adGroupCriterionResult;
        CpcBid criterionCpcBid = null;
        // Find the criterion-level CpcBid among the keyword's bids.
        for (Bids bids : biddableAdGroupCriterion.getBiddingStrategyConfiguration().getBids()) {
          if (bids instanceof CpcBid) {
            CpcBid cpcBid = (CpcBid) bids;
            if (BidSource.CRITERION.equals(cpcBid.getCpcBidSource())) {
              criterionCpcBid = cpcBid;
            }
          }
        }

        System.out.printf(
            "Ad group criterion with ad group ID %d, criterion ID %d, type "
                + "'%s', and bid %d was updated.%n",
            biddableAdGroupCriterion.getAdGroupId(),
            biddableAdGroupCriterion.getCriterion().getId(),
            biddableAdGroupCriterion.getCriterion().getCriterionType(),
            criterionCpcBid.getBid().getMicroAmount());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Any help is appreciated.